# Mantener sesión entre aplicaciones PHP

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, base-de-datos, sesiones

Tengo tres subdominios en una cuenta que administro con Plesk 12, estos subdominios se alojan en el directorio `/var/www/vhosts/dominio/`:

- httpdocs/
- subdominio.dominio/
- otrosubdominio.dominio/

En el dominio principal tengo una aplicación Laravel 5.4 con su respectiva base de datos.

En el primer subdominio tengo una aplicación phpbb también con su base de datos.

En el segundo subdominio tengo otra aplicación PHP también con su base de datos.

Necesito "interconectar" las aplicaciones. En principio intenté usar Passport de Laravel. Luego simplemente una API que probara el usuario y contraseña siempre y cuando la petición se hiciera desde la IP del servidor, pero estoy pensando, ¿cómo mantener la sesión activa entre las aplicaciones?

Pensé en crear una API que se conectara a la base de datos del dominio y que se fijara en una tabla la IP del cliente y si está la sesión activa para entonces "validar" la sesión, pero en un lugar con varias computadoras no serviría... ¿Alguna idea?
Desde ya muchas gracias

Comment: Con include y un archivo qe contenga la sesion creo que podria ser posible

Comment: Gracias @Risa__B por tu comentario, creo que no hace falta un archivo ya que la sesión no es "física"

Answer (score 0):

Lo que debes hacer es editar el archivo **config/session.php** y modificar el dominio de tu cookie de sesión.

Pon ***.dominio.com** y tendrás la cookie con el inicio de sesión en todos los subdominios.

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Cookie Domain
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may change the domain of the cookie used to identify a session
| in your application. This will determine which domains the cookie is
| available to in your application. A sensible default has been set.
|
*/

'domain' => '*.dominio.com',
```